# Pandas for inserting a columns as index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When reading from excel to pandas, it shows like this

```
t0001   Albania 0.03914382317658349
0   t0001   Algeria 0.298994
1   t0001   Austria 1.01137
2   t0001   Belgium 0.306369
```

What I want to achieve is inserting a columns of 'time','region','value', and it should be shows like below

```
    time    region  value
0   t0001   Albania 0.0391438
1   t0001   Algeria 0.298994
2   t0001   Austria 1.01137
3   t0001   Belgium 0.306369
```

Is it possible to achieve in the pandas?

Answer (score 3):

When reading your excel file, read it as so, with a `header` and `names` parameter.

```
df = pd.read_excel(..., header=None, names=['time', 'region', 'value'])
```

---

If you are curious, the fix would be to call `reset_index` and assign columns:

```
df = df.T.reset_index().T
df.columns = ['time', 'region', 'value']

df['value'] = df['value'].astype(float)

df

        time   region     value
index  t0001  Albania  0.039144
0      t0001  Algeria  0.298994
1      t0001  Austria  1.011370
2      t0001  Belgium  0.306369
```

You should strive as much as possible to not reach a point that would necessitate running cleanup code like this.

Answer (score 1):

`Header = None` is the proper solution but as an alternative solution you can also do :

```
df.loc[-1] = df.columns  
df.index += 1
df.columns =  ['time', 'region', 'value']
df.value = df.value.astype(float)
```

```
   time   region                value
1  t0001  Algeria             0.298994
2  t0001  Austria              1.01137
3  t0001  Belgium             0.306369
0  t0001  Albania             0.039143
```